# DataTable in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, datatable

I am new to Vue and have never tried creating my own datatable, which brings me where I am now, suck.

I am trying to create a table where we can have dynamic links and/or buttons on any cell in any row. Mostly it will just end up being a few links in the last cell: edit / delete. I have the table to the point where I can pass in the columns and rows and it will build the table out visually. The filter and paging also work fine. Where I am suck is, how do I update and refresh the table to display new data when something is added or deleted? Plus how do I get the edit and delete buttons to work? Any help or criticism would be appreciated .

Here is my vue page I set up to just test the datatable:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            <button type="button" @click="addNew()">Add New</button>
        </div>
        <h-table :headers="tableHeaders" :rows="tableRows"></h-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { ref, onBeforeMount, watch } from "vue";
    import { dataTable } from '../shared';
    import HTable from '@/components/form-components/h-table';
    
    export default {
        components: {
            HTable,
        },
        setup() {
            let id = ref(3);
            const tableData = ref([
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Mark",
                    color: "Orange"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "David",
                    color: "Red"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "Ashley",
                    color: "Pink"
                },
            ]);


            const tableHeaders = [
                { label: "One" },
                { label: "Two" },
                { label: "Three" },
                { label: "" } //Links
            ];

            let tableRows = [];

            const buildTableRows = () => {
                //Clear the data
                tableRows.value = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < tableData.value.length; i++) {
                    var row = dataTable.buildRow();
                    //Column One
                    dataTable.buildColumn(row, tableData.value[i].id);
                    //Column Two
                    dataTable.buildColumn(row, tableData.value[i].name);
                    //Column Three
                    dataTable.buildColumn(row, tableData.value[i].color);
                    //Column Four
                    var colThree = dataTable.buildColumn(row, "");
                    dataTable.buildLink(colThree, "Edit", "", `editItem(${tableData.value[i].id})`);
                    dataTable.buildLink(colThree, "Delete", "");

                    tableRows.push(row);
                }
            }

            const addNew = () => {
                const newTest = {
                    id: id + 1,
                    name: `Name-${id + 1}`,
                    color: `Color-${id + 1}`
                };

                tableData.value.push(newTest);
            }

            const editItem = (id) => {
                console.log(id);
            };
            const deleteItem = (id) => {
                console.log(id);
            };

            watch(tableData, () => { buildTableRows(); }, { deep: true });

            onBeforeMount(() => {
                buildTableRows();
            });

            return { tableHeaders, tableRows, addNew, editItem, deleteItem }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my data-table.js file

```js
const paginate = (fromArr, pageActive, limitPerPage) => {
    var newArr = Array.from(fromArr);
    var startPaginate = Number(limitPerPage) * Number(pageActive) - (Number(limitPerPage) - 1);
    var endPaginate = Number(limitPerPage) * Number(pageActive);
    return newArr.slice(startPaginate - 1, endPaginate <= newArr.length ? endPaginate : newArr.length);
};

const pageInfo = (fromArr, pageActive, limitPerPage) => {
    var newArr = Array.from(fromArr);
    var startPaginate = Number(limitPerPage) * Number(pageActive) - (Number(limitPerPage) - 1);
    var endPaginate = Number(limitPerPage) * Number(pageActive);
    return {
        from: newArr.length >= 1 ? startPaginate : 0,
        start: newArr.length >= 1 ? startPaginate : 0,
        to: endPaginate <= newArr.length ? endPaginate : newArr.length,
        end: endPaginate <= newArr.length ? endPaginate : newArr.length,
        of: newArr.length,
        length: newArr.length
    };
}

const pages = (fromArr, limitPerPage) => {
    var newArr = Array.from(fromArr);
    var divideLength = newArr.length / Number(limitPerPage);
    var pageNumber = Math.ceil(divideLength);

    return pageNumber;
}

const pagination = (totalPages) => {
    var newArr = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++) {
        newArr.push(i);
    }

    return newArr;
};

const search = (fromArr, searchTerm) => {
    var testing = fromArr.flatMap(obj => {
        const objHasSearchTerm = Object.entries(obj)
            .some(([key, value]) => key !== 'columns' && String(value).toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()));

        if (objHasSearchTerm && !obj.cells) {
            return [obj];
        }

        const matchedChildren = search(obj.columns ?? [], searchTerm);
        return objHasSearchTerm || matchedChildren.length > 0
            ? obj
            : [];
    });

    return testing;
}

const buildRow = (id) => {
    var row = {};
    row.id = id;
    row.columns = [];
    return row;
}

const buildColumn = (row, columnData) => {
    var column = {};
    column.columnData = columnData;
    column.links = [];
    column.buttons = [];

    row.columns.push(column);
    return column;
}

const buildLink = (column, text, url, clickFunction) => {
    var link = {};
    link.text = text;
    link.url = url;
    link.click = clickFunction;

    column.links.push(link);
}

const buildButton = (column, text, url, clickFunction) => {
    var button = {};
    button.text = text;
    button.url = url;
    button.click = clickFunction;

    column.buttons.push(button);
}

export const dataTable = {
    paginate,
    pageInfo,
    pages,
    pagination,
    search,
    buildRow,
    buildColumn,
    buildLink,
    buildButton
}
```

And lastly my datatable component:

```html
<template>
    <div class="datatable">
        <div class="dataTables_length">
            <label>
                Show
                <select v-model="entriesToDisplay" @change="paginiation">
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="100">100</option>
                </select>
                entries
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="dataTables_filter">
            <label>
                Filter:
                <input type="search" v-model="searchInput" class="" placeholder="" @keyup="search">
            </label>
        </div>
        <table class="data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th v-for="header in headers" :key="header.label">{{header.label}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="row in filteredRows" :key="row.id" ref="rows">
                    <td v-for="(column, index) in row.columns" :key="index">
                        <div v-html="column.columnData"></div>
                        <ul v-if="column.links">
                            <li v-for="(link, index) in column.links" :key="index">
                                <a @click="link.click">{{link.text}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li v-for="(button, index) in column.buttons" :key="index">
                                <button @click="button.click">{{button.text}}</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr v-if="!entries.length" class="no-table-data">
                    <td :colspan="headers.length">No Data</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="dataTables_info" id="DataTables_Table_0_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing {{ viewInfo.from }} to {{ viewInfo.to }} of {{ viewInfo.of }} entries <span v-if="searchInput">(filtered from {{ rows.length }} total entries)</span></div>
        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="DataTables_Table_0_paginate">
            <a class="paginate_button previous" :class="{'disabled': currentPage === 1}" @click="paginateEntries('previous', page)">Previous</a>
            <span v-for="page in pages" :key="page">
                <a class="paginate_button" :class="{'current': currentPage === page}" @click="paginateEntries('page', page)">{{page}}</a>
            </span>
            <a class="paginate_button next" :class="{'disabled': currentPage === totalPages}" @click="paginateEntries('next', page)">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
    import { dataTable } from '../../shared';
    export default {
        props: {
            id: String,
            headers: ref({}),
            rows: ref({})
        },
        setup(props) {
            let entries = ref([...props.rows]);
            let currentPage = ref(1);
            let searchInput = ref("");     

            let entriesToDisplay = ref(5);
            let filteredRows = ref(dataTable.paginate(entries.value, 1, entriesToDisplay.value));
            let paginiation = () => filteredRows.value = dataTable.paginate(entries.value, 1, entriesToDisplay.value);

            let totalPages = computed(() => dataTable.pages(entries.value, entriesToDisplay.value))
            const viewInfo = computed(() => dataTable.pageInfo(entries.value, 1, entriesToDisplay.value));
            let pages = computed(() => dataTable.pagination(totalPages.value));

            const search = () => {
                currentPage = 1;
                entries.value = dataTable.search(props.rows, searchInput.value);
                paginateData(entries.value);
                paginiation();
            }
            const paginateData = (data) => {
                filteredRows.value = dataTable.paginate(data, currentPage.value, entriesToDisplay.value);
                totalPages.value = dataTable.pages(data, entriesToDisplay.value);
            }
            const paginateEntries = (action, page) => {
                switch (action) {
                    case "previous":
                        (currentPage.value == 1) ? currentPage.value = 1 : currentPage.value -= 1;
                        break;
                    case "next":
                        (currentPage.value == totalPages.value) ? currentPage.value = totalPages.value : currentPage.value += 1;
                        break;
                    case "page":
                        currentPage.value = page
                        break;
                }
                entries.value = [...props.rows];
                paginateData(entries.value);
            };

            return {
                entries,
                entriesToDisplay,
                currentPage,
                searchInput,
                filteredRows,
                paginiation,
                search,
                paginateData,
                paginateEntries,
                viewInfo,
                totalPages,
                pages
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Making the table reactive

In two instances you're using `ref` objects when you should be using [`computed`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html).  Basically, anything that should automatically "recompute" based on a change to a dependency (tableData) should be a computed property:

**In your datatable component:**

```js
let entries = computed(() => [...props.rows]);
```

```js
let filteredRows = computed(() =>
  dataTable.paginate(entries.value, 1, entriesToDisplay.value)
);
```

**In the parent vue page**:

Here you've created `tableRows` as a standard array when it should actually be a `ref` array:

```js
let tableRows = ref([]);
```

and then there's one line you need to update to use `.value`:

```js
const buildTableRows = () => {
  ...
  tableRows.value.push(row);
}
```

Now you should notice new entries being added to the table when pressing the Add button

#### Creating working Edit button

First, I noticed in `buildTableRows` you're calling a function `buildRow()` in your data-table.js file that expects an id, but you forgot to pass that in, so here's that fix:

```js
var row = dataTable.buildRow(tableData.value[i].id);
```

Then in the same function, creating the edit button using `buildLink` expects a function as the fourth parameter which you should do by just providing the function name (passing in parameters will be handled in the datatable component):

```js
dataTable.buildLink(colThree, 'Edit', '', editItem);
```

In that datatable component is where you would pass in your row.id parameter (which is now no longer undefined thanks to the fix above).

```html
<li v-for="(link, index) in column.links" :key="index">
  <a @click="link.click(row.id)">{{ link.text }}</a>
</li>
```

Now when you click the Edit button in your data table you will see your `editItem` function console logging the row id.  With the id, you can retrieve that row from `tableData` and do with it what you want...  Setting up the delete button would be the same way!